# How to access anonymous control's result?

Tags: c#, events, anonymous-function

I have this code

```
 textBox1.MouseDown += (o, em) => 
if (new FolderBrowserDialog
    { 
        RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop 
    }.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
    {   
        textBox1.Text =  // how do I know HERE, that what was the selected folder in the dialog box?
        // something like
        // textBox1.Text = thisDialogBox.SelectedFolder; 
    }
```

I know there are many other ways, I could create a variable for this dialog box and and do what I need, or not use a anonymous function etc. But that's not the point, what I wanna know is

How do I access this control in this context, given its anonymity?

**EDIT :** Okay, as Grant pointed out, its not about anonymity, but that I don't have a reference to it, so is there a possible way of getting its access *without storing its reference*?

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.MouseDown += (o, em) =>
{
    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog
    { 
        RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop 
    };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
    {   
        textBox1.Text = dialog.SelectedFolder;
    }
}
```

Okay, may be it is not exact answer to the question, but it is the only sane way to do this.

Comment: yeah, thanks but I think I knew that myself. Did you read the question? I wanna know if there is a way to access it without declaring the variable.

Comment: @Razort4x I didn't read it carefully first, but to be honest your question doesn't make any sense, why would you want to do this? Is it kind of puzzle or what?

Comment: lol! No man, it aint no puzzle. But I was just doing this and it came to my mind how can I access it this way.

Comment: @Razort4x you should have very strong reasons to avoid doing it normal way.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done without storing a reference to the `FolderBrowserDialog`. In your example, once `ShowDialog` is terminated, the `FolderBrowserDialog` is out of scope. Your only alternative would be to store a reference:

```
textBox1.MouseDown += (o, em) =>
{
    using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
};
```

Comment: come on man! You didn't have to answer for that, you could have said that in a comment, did you read my comment to previous answer or my edit part of question before posting? But anyways, thanks for trying!